# Use Ansible to Turn off SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support?

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, centos, smb

My goal is to use ansible to turn off this "windows feature" that can be found on a windows machine by searching "Turn Windows features on or off" and going down to SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support.

Something is wrong with my code and I cannot get the setting disabled, please help.

CODE:

```
- name: Turn off SMB
  hosts: myhosts
  become_method: runas

  vars:
    ansible_become_password: mysecurepasswordthatsnot123

  tasks:
   - win_shell: Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol
    become: yes
    become_user: user
```

What is wrong with my play?? Error has to do with non interactive mode??

Comment: Can you post the exact error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about win_shell.. but ansible doc suggests to use [win_optional_feature](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_optional_feature_module.html#win-optional-feature-module). Have you tried this way?

also, there is a sample play available at this [link](https://github.com/juju4/ansible-harden-windows/blob/master/tasks/windows-feature.yml) for windows features using win_command.. check it out.

i am sure you would have seen this [blog](https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2019/07/issue-removing-smb1-from-windows-with-ansible.html)

Comment: The win optional feature worked! The syntax was tricky for the first 5 mins, but got it to work. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Great.. accept the answer if your requirement is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about win_shell.. but ansible doc suggests to use win_optional_feature. Have you tried this way?

also, there is a sample play available at this link for windows features using win_command.. check it out.

i am sure you would have seen this blog